# How to parse string value "(20)" to Integer in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a string "(20)". I need to convert it to an int. I read `parseInt` is a function which helps me to achieve that, but i don't know how.

Comment: You'll need to get rid of the parentheses first.

Answer (score 1):

Use string slicing and `parseInt()`

```
var str = "(20)"
str = str.slice(1, -1) // remove parenthesis
var integer = parseInt(str) // make it an integer
console.log(integer) // 20
```

One Line version

```
var integer = parseInt("(20)".slice(1, -1))
```

The slice method slices the string by the start and end index, start is 1, because that’s the (, end is -1, which means the last one - ), therefore the () will be stripped. Then `parseInt()` turns it into an integer.

Or use regex so it can work with other cases, credits to @adeithe

```
var integer = parseInt("(20)".match(/\d+/g))
```

It will match the digits and make it an integer

Read more:

- [slicing strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to achieve this

```
var str = "(20)"
parseInt(str.match(/\d+/g).join())
```

Comment: though I dislike using regex, this method is safer since it doesn't slice first and last character. it just looks for digits and parses them so it works with this and OTHER cases.

Comment: Why would you need `join()`?

Comment: you dont, too used to type strict languages

Answer (score 0):

Easy, use this

```
var number = parseInt((string).substr(2,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner version of Hedy's

```js
var str = "(20)";
var str_as_integer = parseInt(str.slice(1, -1))
```

Comment: This is identical to my answer apart from the explanations, you could have edited my answer instead

Comment: @Hedy Sorry! You answered faster than I have haha, should've refreshed

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract that number first, you can use the match method and a regex \d wich means "digits". Then you can parse that number

```js
let str = "(20)";
console.log(parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)));
```